# How to edit a file in folder belonging to a user with no login?

Tags: macos

Pretty much as the title suggests. Is there a nice way of doing this? At the moment, I need to change permissions to the folder before being able to access the file.

Just to reiterate, the user has no login capability, so I can't `su` to the user that the folder belongs to.

The file is a simple config file that I want to open with `vim` for editing and it's in a folder that's owned by a user and group created for a service, the user and group for which owns the folder.

Comment: Can you add some `ls -l` output of the directories/files involved so we see the access permissions? Also, with which tool/editor do you edit these files?

Comment: @xoteric, can you please **edit the question** to add some details based on the comments above and beneath the answer?

Comment: @nohillside, I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks. It's usually way simpler to list the relevant directories/files with `ls -l` and add the result to the question than to describe it with words. But does the answer below work for you?

Comment: Note: You can use `exec sudo -u <user> zsh` as a close substitute for `su <user>`. A major difference is you enter your own password.

Comment: @Xoteric I've added an answer, can you check if it solves your issue?

Comment: I've gotten side tracked, I'll get back to it soon, will see if your answer makes sense soon.

Comment: @Xoteric I was wondering if you have had a chance to check my answer.

Comment: @jaume No, sorry still haven't got back to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to edit the file in Terminal with `vim`:

```
sudo -u <name of user with no login> vim /folder/file
```

where:

- `sudo -u` lets you run a command as the user specified by the `-u` option
- `<name of user with no login>` is the account name of the user the folder belongs to, as returned by this Terminal command:

  ```
  stat -f "%Su" /folder
  ```

  If you get a `Permission denied` error, try this command instead:

  ```
  stat -f "%Su" $(dirname /folder)
  ```

  (replace `folder` with the folder hierarchy where `file` is located)
- `vim /folder/file` launches `vim` (replace `file` with the name of the file and `folder` with the folder hierarchy where `file` is located)

When using `sudo` this way, you are running a command **on behalf of the user without having to log in as that user**.

You can replace `vim` with other command-line editor of your choice, like `pico`, an easy-to-use command-line file editor. You won't be able to use an app to edit the file, though.

Comment: Finally got around to this. Worked like a charm. Many thanks!